# Related to Python reading file

Tags: python-3.x, file-read

I am trying to read one file to find the duplicates but it is giving permission error.

```
f= open("C:\\users\\pam\\Desktop",'r')
print(f.readlines())
```

> error- PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\users\pam\Desktop'

Comment: Are you in some private network, like on a company's system ?

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

Comment: Use `.strip()` on the strings in the output?

Comment: You just changed the question completely ! Please ask a new question and also do some research before posting your question !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are pointing the path to your Desktop folder. This will cause the error. You can only `open` on a file.